# Print manually on both sides powerpoint 2010 files

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'd like to print a presentation 3 slides in each printing page. and I'd like to print on both sides of the paper, using a printer that doesn't support automatic duplex printing. 
How can I configute powerpoint to print first all the odd papers (which are not the odd slide number, remember there are 3 slides in each page) and then the pair even page number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printer must support duplexing manually. Otherwise you must print page by page.

Comment: It's weired that Microsoft doesn't provide a solution that doesn't rely on the printer's abilites. There is such a solution for MS-Word. Similar to the ability to print current page, range of pages, etc. It a common requirement and very easy to implement

Comment: You may print to acrobat pdf (or bullzip) , it allows to print odd pages, even pages so that you can manually duplex.